# How to retrieve data from two column using foreach

Tags: php, pdo

Hello I am creating gaming trophy system and I am still learning pdo. I have two tables in my database

First table ( games ) structure is

```
id, title, thumb, bronze, silver, gold, platinum
```

Second table ( trophies ) structure is

```
id, title, game_id
```

every trophy assigned to a game by ( game_id ) column

I want to list the games as follow

game name

earned trophies **x** from **total**

the query am using only get the total of the trophies i don't know how to retrieve game trophy data from trophies table

this is my query code

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM trophies ORDER BY id DESC');
$numcat = $stmt->rowCount();
if($numcat == 0)
{
    echo "There's No Trophies To Show";
}
else
{
    foreach($db->query("SELECT thumb, title, id, SUM(bronze + silver + gold + platinum) AS total FROM games GROUP BY id DESC") as $row)
    {
        echo "
        <div class='game_row'>
            <div class='thumb_box'><img src='../images/thumbs/$row[thumb]' width='87' height='48' alt='$row[title]' /></div>
            <div class='info_box'>
                <span class='game_name'><a href='trophies.php?action=edit&game_id=$row[id]'>$row[title]</a></span><br />
                <span class='game_trophy'>0 Of $row[total] Trophies</span>
            </div>
        </div>";
    }
}
```

I tried to use join and iam sure iam missing something

My query with join

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT thumb, title, id, SUM(bronze + silver + gold + platinum) AS total FROM games JOIN trophies ON games.id = trophies.game_id GROUP BY id DESC") as $row)
```

the error i got

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in the same line

Comment: `join` is one of the solutions

Comment: @curious_coder i tried join and got foreach error i dont know how to solve could you please write the query with join coz i think iam missing something

Comment: I concur with curious_coder, if you join the two tables, you'll have all your date in one object, so that you wont have to iterate through two different data sets.

Comment: Zeroic, please post your foreach statement and error, along with your query data results after join.

Comment: @EricLeroy Hello i put my query and the error i got

Comment: try running the join query directly in your phpmyadmin or anything of your choice and check if there are any errors in statement. I doubt there will be any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do that:

```
$sqlres=$db->query("SELECT thumb, title, id, SUM(bronze + silver + gold + platinum) AS total FROM games JOIN trophies ON games.id = trophies.game_id GROUP BY id DESC");
while($row=$sqlres->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo $row["thumb"];
}
```

In SQL when you do a join you need to specify the table of the field:

```
SELECT g.thumb, g.title, g.id, SUM(t.bronze + t.silver + t.gold + platinum) AS total FROM games g JOIN trophies t ON g.id = t.game_id GROUP BY g.id DESC
```

Comment: I Got this error Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'title' in field list is ambiguous in and the query line and this error in the next line Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in

Comment: The error is caused because there are `title` in both the tables. To avoid that you can specify as `games.title` and `trophies.title`

Comment: @Aragon0 Your second code i edited t.bronze to g.bronze because its in the games table not trophies table but i got strange result but iam happy coz no Errors

Comment: This is the query that fix my problem but i think i need to do more edits to achive what i need thanks for fixing my problems

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$rows = $db->query("SELECT thumb, title, id, SUM(bronze + silver + gold + platinum) AS total FROM games JOIN trophies ON games.id = trophies.game_id GROUP BY id DESC");

foreach($rows as $r){
   echo $r->thumb //etc.
}
```

Your title sql error is because you have two tables with the same field name. You must specify duplicate fields in a standard join like so: games.title, trophies.bronze, etc. etc. ( it's good practice to do it for all, but is only required on tables with the same fields.  Hence the ambiguous fields error. -  I know.  MySQL needs to display better errors.  Too bad Oracle bought them up, and hasn't focused on it.

And then, trying running the foreach loop on your sql query after returning the query results so you can use it to iterate through the result rows.

Comment: i tried your code and got this error in the query line PDO::query() [pdo.query]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'title' in field list is ambiguous in

Answer (score 1):

probably is the field id ambiguous change your query

```
SELECT games.thumb, games.title, games.id, SUM(games.bronze + games.silver + games.gold + games.platinum) AS total FROM games JOIN trophies ON games.id = trophies.game_id GROUP BY games.id DESC"
```

Comment: i got this error in the query line Warning: PDO::query() [pdo.query]: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'game.thumb' in 'field list' in

Comment: sorry game should be games ( the name of your table)